# Assigning value from textfield to a variable

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I transfer a value from textfield in the variable?

[CODE]

```
import flash.text.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.*;

//Button named Player_save
Player_save.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, savename);

function savename(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    playerlist.text=player_name.text;
    trace(player_name.text);
    //player_name.text is the textfield 
}
```

[/CODE]

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
var myVariable:String = player_name.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare the variable, then assign the text value from the textfield to it.

var playerName:String = player_name.text;

Answer (score 0):

try this:
var _pName = player_name.text;